# How to do N: N join in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

user table

```
user.find(1)
id: 3,
name: 'hoge',
gender: 0
```

org_users table

```
user.find(1).org_users
id: 1,
org_id: 1,
user_id: 3,
status: 'in progress'
```

I would like to do inner join the above two tables as follows:

```
id: 3,
name: 'hoge',
gender: 0,
status: 'in progress'
```

I thought I could do it with the following command, but for some reason I can't see the result of the org_users table

```
User.joins(:org_users).select("org_users.*, users.*")
```

result:

```
User.joins(:org_users).select("org_users.*, users.*")
  User Load (0.6ms)  SELECT org_users.*, users.* FROM `users` INNER JOIN `org_users` ON `org_users`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` LIMIT 11
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<User id: 1, name: "hoge", gender: 0, created_at: "2019-12-20 14:00:38", updated_at: "2019-12-20 14:00:38">]>
```

SELECT org_users.*, users.* FROM `users` INNER JOIN `org_users` ON `org_users`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` LIMIT 11

If the generated query is directly hit to mysql, the information of org_users will appear

I don't know why the two results are different.

please let me know if there is anything i misunderstood.

My source code is at the following URL

https://github.com/negabaro/railsTestJoins

The model configuration is as follows.

app/models/org.rb

```
class Org < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :org_users
  has_many :users, through: :org_users
end
```

app/models/org_user.rb

```
class OrgUser < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :org
  belongs_to :user
end
```

app/models/user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :org_users
  has_many :orgs, through: :org_users
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
users = User.joins(:org_users).select('users.id, users.name, users.gender, org_users.status')
```

Will do the trick. It will generate something like this:
`#<User:0x00005649f318dc68 id: user_id, name: name ... and so on>`

You can do `users.first.attributes` and it will show you desired hash:

```
{
id: id,
name: name,
gender: gender,
status: status
}
```

Comment: I see!! Thank you for letting me know